Why does LuaLaTeX find fonts but XeLaTeX does not?
I am back to using LaTeX after a while, and I have a very basic question.
I am on MacOS, so I installed MacTeX and TeXstudio and everything works perfectly fine! But this puzzles me.
I am compiling an old document that uses the font Lato Hairline, which is not installed in my MacOS system fonts (I do not find it in the Font Book app). In my document notes, I had specified to compile it with LuaLaTeX; it works perfectly, despite not having that font installed.
If instead of LuaLaTeX I use XeLaTeX, it complains (understandably so), with:

Package fontspec Error: The font "Lato Hairline" cannot be found.
\newfontfamily

Where does LuaLaTeX pull the fonts from? How come I can use a font that is not installed in my system? Or is this font installed elsewhere as part of the MacTeX installation? If so, where can I see it?
Thanks!

You could also ask why they manage to usually get the same answer using completely different methods. xetex uses kpathsea (like tex file searching) for file names and fontconfig (like system font appilciations) for internal font names. luatex uses a custom font cache search written in Lua

xelatex is much more picky about font names that lualatex. Also it uses your system fontconfig while lualatex builds its own database.

"with LuaLaTeX; it works perfectly, despite not having that font installed." you must have the font somewhere

Where can I check the database lualatex builds and which fonts it has available? where would this Lato Hairline be installed?

lualatex records the full path to all fonts used in the terminal and in the log at the end of the run, so finding the font should be easy

I see this in the .log file: Font names database loaded from /Users/dcarbajo/Library/texlive/2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz is there where the otf files of the fonts used are?

I cannot find Lato Hairline explicitly in the log though... In the end I just want to see which fonts I can use with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX and where they are located

what fonts does it log (not the cache, the list of fonts) the end of the console output for any document should look like  406 words of node memory still in use:    3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes   avail lists: 1:1,2:94,3:12,4:1,5:25,6:6,7:142,8:10,9:78 </usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf> Output written on aa969.pdf (1 page, 3068 bytes).
with something other than lmroman10-regular if you are not using latin modern

Ah found it! (sorry I had changed to Arial in the tests and I was looking at the wrong log), it finds it here: /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/typoland/lato/Lato-Hairline.ttf

So I guess my questions now are: is this a font installed as part of MacTeX? Where can I find a list of fonts installed by MacTeX to choose which ones to use? ...and why LuaLaTeX can use these fonts but XeLaTeX cannot?

Any clue on how to specify/know where LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX retrieve the fonts from?
